# Should I take up with the new HR Chief?

Tags: management, human-resources, ethics, politics

TL;DR:
I was terminated from a position which was "not important" to the company. The management was unfair and absolutely disregarded my efforts. Following "changes" which I was a part of, HR chief was also replaced. #Question#

---

During the happy-go-lucky days of company two years ago, I was hired for a "maintenance" position as a developer. My product was practically non-important to the company, but apparently they hired me because I was working in a good company and had sound educational background.

Within a month my product was changed and for an year I received favorable reviews and love and support of the team. I also realized, however that my company was neck deep in office politics and there are practically not rules of ethics. Actually, there were no rules whatsoever. Incompetent managers made decisions at their whim and HR existed like a ghost. This is a small midcap company but once a leader in their domain (now declining, steadily).

Dark clouds started setting last year when company started reporting losses, and board started changing key managers. I noticed it but did not pay much attention. My manager become very cold and indifferent towards the later half of that year and assigned me a cryptic number as as rating. I asked around, and none of the members had never received any ratings.
The culture of my team was so terrifying that I did not even ask about the meaning of the rating. Even asking questions had strong retaliations. The comments in the review were "to improve" and manager always avoided any discussion remotely close to the ratings. I completed all the assignments he suggested and even more in that quarter, but he assigned me even poorer ratings in the following quarter.
Later in that quarter, I was in a call with manager and HR, where they informed me of my termination. That was it! I never had a conversation larger than 5 minutes with the manager in the last six months and I don't even get to tell my side to the HR. My access was immediately revoked, and I was told to leave office within 30 minutes.

I heard that the same day HR Chief was also replaced, and not the best words were said by CEO in his departure. This was one of the most political companies, and I never knew about this.
When I sent a request to new chief on LinkedIn saying I need help, they quickly accepted but I did not approach for 5 months thinking I may not want to head back to that company.

I now believe that most of the companies run on politics and that may not be the best decision. Should I talk to the chief again? Any other help is greatly appreciated, it could change my life.

Thanks

Comment: 5 months later ? It's too late. What's your goal by approaching HR chief anyway ?

Comment: That's a long story... What is your question? What do want to take to the new HR guy? What is your objective in doing this?

Answer (score 5):

No. That company is toxic. Sever all ties, get a new job with a different company and put it behind you.

I know it's hard to let go when you feel you have been treated unfairly, but the only way forward is to move on to a better future and not look back.

Answer (score 2):

Your comments says "The company is heavily focused on a new alternative product line and is doing well. I wish I could get any positions...". If that is the case and you think it has changed from the hellhole you describe, then sure, reach out, what do you have to lose? But don't rely too much on the loyalty; that sounds like you feel the company owes you. For sure mention, your loyalty, but also emphasise all the knowledge you have and what you can offer them.

BUT the place you described sounds awful. Even if they are doing well, do you really think the entire culture has been turned around. I would be *very* concerned that external success is masking the fact it hasn't changed, to at least some extent, internally. Change is hard and sometimes a known-quantity, even a bad one like this can *seem* really tempting. But sometimes you just have to move on.